# Why am i unable to download MySql?

Tags: mysql, installation, configuration

I am trying to install MySql in my system. While configuring I am getting an error as "#TimeActionMessageDuration / Fetch1119:55:02Could not connect, server may not be running.Unable to connect to localhost". I cannot seen to figure out the issue and I am not being able to find port 3306 in cmd. Kindly help

I tried looking for the status of port 3306 in cmd - no result
Uninstalled and reistalled - same issue persists

Comment: 'server may not be running' - did you check services for windows? what os are you?

Comment: I have windows 10... do you think the windows might not be compatible?